# Calculating the total data+overhead of a set associative cache

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

This is a question from a Computer Architecture exam and I don't understand how to get to the correct answer.

Here is the question:

> This question deals with main and cache memory only.
>
> Address size: 32 bits
>   Block size: 128 items
>   Item size: 8 bits
>   Cache Layout: 6 way set associative
>   Cache Size: 192 KB (data only)
>   Write policy: Write Back
>
> What is the total number of cache bits?

In order to get the number of tag bits, I find that 7 bits of the address are used for byte offset (0-127) and 8 bits are used for the block number (0-250) (250 = 192000/128/6), therefore 17 bits of the address are left for the tag.

To find the total number of bits in the cache, I would take (`valid bit` + `tag size` + `bits per block`) * `number of blocks per set` * `number of sets` = (1 + 17 + 1024) * 250 * 6 = **1,536,000**. This is not the correct answer though.

The correct answer is **1,602,048** total bits in the cache and part of the answer is that there are 17 tag bits. After trying to reverse engineer the answer, I found that 1,602,048 = 1043 * 256 * 6 but I don't know if that is relevant to the solution because I don't know why those numbers would be used.

I'd like if someone could explain what I did wrong in my calculation to get a different answer.

Comment: 192 KB is 192*1024, so the number of cache sets is 256, not 250. It seems to me that the "Write policy: Write Back" part of the question suggests that each cache block requires a dirty bit in addition to a valid bit. Therefore, (2 + 17 + 1024) * 256 * 6 = 1,602,048. That said, a writeback cache doesn't necessarily need a dirty bit actually. This aspect of the design is part of the coherence protocol, not the write policy. So the answer  (1 + 17 + 1024) * 256 * 6 is also correct, and I can argue it's "more correct" because the question doesn't say anything about coherence.

Comment: @HadiBrais Thank you, that makes sense. I assumed KB meant 1000 bytes and KiB would be 1024 bytes, but it definitely seems they were referring to kibibytes. Since it was a multiple choice test and "1536000" was not an option, I chose "1600512" which is (1 + 17 + 1024) * 256 * 6. Do you think if I bring up what you mentioned about coherence I have a chance at getting points back for that question?

Comment: It really depends what kind of person your teacher is :P. You can certainly try.

Comment: You can tell them that mentioning the write policy doesn't affect the total cache size in any way. They should have instead mentioned in the question that the coherence protocol is MSI. The write policy is irrelevant.